# resizing a matrix in C

Tags: c, data-structures

I have a function that makes a matrix bigger in C. it works the first time you use it, but on the second time, I get `realloc(): invalid old size`. Any ideas on what might be happening?

Here's the code:

```
int** resize_matrix(int** matrix, long org_size, long size_inc){

  long new_size = org_size + size_inc;
  int** new;
  int* temp;

  new = realloc(matrix, new_size*sizeof(int*));

  for(long i=0; i<org_size; i++){
    //error happens here, when i=0, but only the second time you run it
    temp = realloc(new[i], new_size*sizeof(int));
    new[i] = temp;
    //clears the added space
    for(long i2=org_size; i2<new_size; i2++){
      new[i][i2] = 0;
    }
  }

  for(long i = org_size; i<new_size; i++){
    new[i] = calloc(new_size, sizeof(int));
  }

  return new;
}
```

Comment: at the end it should say "return new", I forgot to change it lol

Comment: Please add code to check if realloc() or `calloc()` fails (returns NULL).  Also please show how you call this function...it's quite possible there error is there.

Comment: @e2298  What is old_size?

Comment: @JohnZwinck checked for errors on malloc() and calloc(), there were none. I just call it by : `adjacency_matrix = resize_matrix(adjacency_matrix, number_of_nodes,100);`

Comment: I ran `int** am = malloc(1); am = resize_matrix(am, 0, 100); am = resize_matrix(am, 100, 200);` and it worked fine with no errors at all.  So...something else is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Found the mistake, It was something after the call to resize_matrix, that just so happened to stop my output at the right time to make me think it was resize_matrix that caused it. Sorry for taking your time.